# How to map a score to a grade based on a list of ranges?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a score which I need to testify against one of the ranges given (see below). Return the string for that range where the score lies.

```
{
        "1" : "Perfect",
        "0.85-1" : "Good",
        "0.60-0.84" : "Medium",
        "0.34-0.59" : "Poor",
        "0-0.33": "No"
}
```

For example, if score is 0.45 then I should get "Poor".

Is there any way to implement this in JavaScript without using 5 if else (or switch case) statements?

Comment: Yes, you can use a loop, but you don't want to start with that data structure. You want to start with an array of objects, `[{max: 0.33, value: "No"}, {max: 0.59, value: "Poor"}, ...`

Comment: Your question looks like it's probably about homework or similar. If so, it's important to *say* that. See [*How do I ask and answer homework questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : you were close, it's work related.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Can you edit your question to include a [mre] of what you’ve written so far, along with a succinct explanation of why it doesn’t meet your requirements, per [ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the data structure to an array to make looping through it simple:

```
const levels = [
    {min: 1,    value: "Perfect"},
    {min: 0.85, value: "Good"},
    {min: 0.60, value: "Medium"},
    {min: 0.34, value: "Poor"},
    {min: 0,    value: "No"},
];

function findLevel(score) {
    for (const {min, value} of levels) {
        if (score >= min) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`${score} is out of range`); // or whatever
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const levels = [
    {min: 1,    value: "Perfect"},
    {min: 0.85, value: "Good"},
    {min: 0.60, value: "Medium"},
    {min: 0.34, value: "Poor"},
    {min: 0,    value: "No"},
];

function findLevel(score) {
    for (const {min, value} of levels) {
        if (score >= min) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    throw new Error(`${score} is out of range`); // or whatever
}

function test(score) {
    console.log(`${score}: ${findLevel(score)}`);
}

test(1);
test(0.5);
test(0.7);
test(0.85);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the keys using `Object.keys()` and iterate each of them with a `forEach()`. Then `split()` each key conditions. Then just use an `if` statement to check if the value is between the condition limits:

```js
const obj = {
        "1" : "Perfect",
        "0.85-1" : "Good",
        "0.60-0.84" : "Medium",
        "0.34-0.59" : "Poor",
        "0-0.33": "No"
}

const points = 0.45;
let result = "";

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  const cond = key.split("-");
  if (cond[0] <= points && cond[1] >= points) { result = obj[key]; }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this.

```js
var scoreConfig = {
  "1" : "Perfect",
  "0.85-1" : "Good",
  "0.60-0.84" : "Medium",
  "0.34-0.59" : "Poor",
  "0-0.33": "No"
}
var score = 0.45;

var scoreKey = Object.keys(scoreConfig).filter(key => {
  const range = key.split("-");
  if(range.length == 1) 
    return range[0] == score
  if(range.length == 2)
    return score > range[0] && score < range[1]
})[0]

console.log(scoreConfig[scoreKey])
```

But it's really not how you should do it!
Overthink your score configuration and store it like this:

```
{
        perfect: {min: 1, max: 1},
        good: {min: 0.85, max: 0.99},
        medium: {min: 0.60, max: 0.84},
        poor: {min: 0.34, max: 0.59},
        no: {min: 0, max: 0.33}
}
```

Then you can loop through with a for...in loop:

```
for( let key in config ) {
   config[key].max 
   config[key].min
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start with a function `between` that takes `min` (inclusive), `max` (exclusive) and `grade`. It returns a function that takes a `score` and return either the grade or nil:

```js
const between = (min, max, grade) => score =>
  score >= min && score < max ? grade : null;
```

Then build a function `or` that takes a list of functions *then* an `x`. Starting with the leftmost function, apply each function to `x` until one returns a truthy value. Returns that value (or nil).

```js
const or = (...fn) => x => {
  let ret;
  for (let i=0; !(ret=fn[i](x)) && i<fn.length; i++);
  return ret;
}
```

Now we can use `between` and `or` to build a `grade` function:

```
const grade = or( between(1    , Infinity , "Perfect")
                , between(0.85 , 1        , "Good"   )
                , between(0.60 , 0.85     , "Medium" )
                , between(0.34 , 0.60     , "Poor"   )
                , between(0    , 0.34     , "No"     ));

grade(1);
//=> "Perfect"

grade(0.92);
//=> "Good"
```

Of course if that's too much "ceremony" I find nested ternaries perfectly readable for these simple cases:

```
const grade = score =>
  ( score >= 1                    ? "Perfect"
  : score >= 0.85 && score < 1    ? "Good"
  : score >= 0.60 && score < 0.85 ? "Medium"
  : score >= 0.34 && score < 0.60 ? "Poor"
                                  : "No")
```